# Do iam permissions prevent from viewing objects (images) by pasting their URLs?

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I have a basic chat application in GO, where users can create group threads and exchange messages and images which are stored inside these threads. Each thread is associated with its own cloud storage bucket and additionally the URLs of the images in a bucket are saved in Postgres. Right now I've set the permissions so that only the users that belong to a certain thread can view the images stored in its corresponding bucket with the help of this [article](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/using-iam-permissions#code-samples_2).

What I don't understand is if a user that doesn't belong to a certain thread (and doesn't have view permissions for that bucket) can he still view the images inside it if he has their URLs?

Comment: Maybe yes, maybe no. Edit your question with the details on the security settings for the bucket and objects.

Comment: Do you use fine grained or uniform permission on Buckets?

Comment: I use uniform permissions.

Comment: Please share the IAM Role that you are using and the related permissions. What have been the results with the given role and permissions? When you say I use uniform permissions, do you mean you’re using Uniform bucket-level access? By the way, have you tested this yourself?